# split sentence into two strings and display iteratively

Tags: java

So I have a long list of words like this and based on the first space I want to split the words into **word-meaning**. Basically I am using `Apache POI` for this as I have to read the docx file and then fetch the data from it.

```
    abash  humiliate, embarrass
    abdicate  relinquish power or position
    aberrant  abnormal
    abet  aid, encourage (typically of crime)
    abeyance  postponement
    aboriginal  indigenous 
    abridge  shorten
    abstemious  moderate
...
```

So what regex would suit my purpose so that I can display it like:

```
word :abash
meaning : humiliate, embarrass
...
```

MY code is :

```
public class WordFileReader {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("E:\\important.docx");
                org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor oleTextExtractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(new XWPFDocument(fis));
                System.out.print(oleTextExtractor.getText());            
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

}
```

--Edit-- 
Based on a suggested answer I am using this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("E:\\Words.docx");
                org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor oleTextExtractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(new XWPFDocument(fis));
                //System.out.print(oleTextExtractor.getText());

                Scanner sc = new Scanner(oleTextExtractor.getText());            
                while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                 String line = sc.nextLine();
                 int i = line.indexOf(' ');
                 String word = line.substring(0, i);
                 String meaning = line.substring(i).trim();

                 System.out.println("word "+word);
                 System.out.println("meaning "+meaning);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

But i get

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at WordFileReader.main(WordFileReader.java:25)
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a regex for such a problem.

Comment: read line by line and for each line perhaps you first split by " " and then separate first and remaining strings...? with out using regex

Comment: Use `String.Split()`. Problem solved, there's no need of any buggy regex to make it complex .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use java.util.Scanner to extract lines from text

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(oleTextExtractor.getText());            
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    ...
```

then I would split the line into word and meaning

```
 int i = line.indexOf(' ', 2);  // start from pos 2 to avoid a article
 String word = txt.substring(0, i);
 String meaning = txt.substring(i).trim();
```

or

```
 String[] parts = line.split("(?<!^a)\\s+", 2);
 String word = parts[0];
 String meaning = parts[1];
```

Comment: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
 at WordFileReader.main(WordFileReader.java:25)

Comment: thit means a line with no ' ' in it, possibly empty

Comment: How can I escape such a line and move forward

Comment: I added `if(line.contains(" "))` condition before substing contructs and it works

Comment: just missed one more thing i.e. there are a few words only in case where they start with a but are treated as one word like: word is `a cappella` and meaning  `without accompaniment` it now displays like a-cappella  without accompaniment

Comment: i see, try int i = line.indexOf(' ', 2);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31520/discussion-between-prateek-and-evgeniy-dorofeev)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`java.lang.String.split(String regex, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
String[] parts = line.split("\\s", 1)
String word = parts[0];
String meaning = parts[1];
```

Comment: hey this sounds cool as it would split as I expected but how do I go line by line via loop any quick idea for that

Comment: is `\s` invalid escape sequence

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring as follows:

```
int index = line.indexOf(" ");
```

"word : "+ line.substring(0, index)+"\n Meaning : "+line.substring(index+1)

Answer (score 0):

Below code works fine for me..I used BufferedReader to read the text from file.

```
BufferedReader br=null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\test.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line="";
    String [] parts=null;
    String everything="",word="",meaning="";
        try {
            line = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);

        parts= line.split(" ",2);
        word=parts[0];
        meaning=parts[1];

    System.out.println("word:"+word.toString());
    System.out.println("meaning:"+meaning.toString());

        sb.append("\n");
            try {
                line = br.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }

} finally {
        try {
            br.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```